addEventListener capture a 'change' event driven by a 3rd party js lib
is it possible to capture a change (or other) event driven by a 3rd party javascript lib?
im using an 'widget' for the number input that offers plus and minus buttons. when either increment or decrement is clicked (by the user) it fires an event which changes the number.
im currently listening to change but if fails to function.
said widget merely utilizes the following input element.

<input type="number" name="quantity" pattern="[0-9]+">

its code simply sets the value on the standard input as follows
this.input.value = quantity;

when 'input.value' is set, is an event fired?!
MDN states the following, noting 'when the user modifies'

The change event is fired for <input>, <select>, and <textarea>
elements when the user modifies the element's value. Unlike the input
event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each alteration
to an element's value. MDN Web

its possible to insert code into the widget but hoping to keep them isolated.

You'll need more details, i.e. what is this widget? What is your code?

If there's an element on your page, you can capture events. Without knowing more details however it's very hard to help with specifics.

"when 'input.value' is set, is an event fired?!" - no, setting a field value via JavaScript, does not trigger the change or input event for that field.

The extension would have to trigger the event explicitly.

all the docs pointed in that direction. thanks
